# I can't write drop or rename table code in Stack Overflow using Chrome

Tags: support, google-chrome

I was writing an answer to a question in Stack Overflow and it involved writing `drop table`, and `remove table` commands. I noticed I kept getting an error on submit, after a little trial and error I noticed these two lines of code were problematic.

```
DROP TABLE contacts
```

and

```
RENAME TABLE contactstemp TO contacts
```

I couldn't figure out a way to submit it. Eventually I used Mozilla Firefox and copy and pasted my answer there, and it worked fine.

Is this a known issue?

ED: Of course, this submits just fine via Chrome. So, I'm baffled.

Comment: You have an overzealous firewall or router on your network.

Comment: How does that work?

Comment: Your network router or firewall is trying to 'prevent' a SQL injection attack by aborting any connection that has the text 'DROP TABLE' in it.

Comment: Work-around: Use SSL.

Comment: I'm betting overzealous Chrome add on. We're not doing any deep packet inspection here.

Comment: Disable all the plugins in Chrome and try...

Comment: Disabled all plugins still didn't work. I sniffed the connection using Wireshark and it never leaves our network. Martijn Pieters answer is correct. I love learning new things, even small stuff.

Comment: How does one NOT use SSL with Stackoverflow? Leading to the further question: how can the firewalling device know what's in the submission? Is this an extreme proxy?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have an overzealous firewall or router operating on your network that is trying to prevent SQL injection attacks. It is aborting the connection because you used a naughty word. Cisco's Intrusion Prevention System does this, for example.

The work-around is to post over SSL instead; although SSL isn't officially supported yet, it does work just fine when posting an answer.

If this worked in Firefox, you probably have HTTPS-Everywhere installed and unwittingly used posted over HTTPS *already* when you switched to that browser.

Comment: How does that effect Chrome, but not Firefox ?

Comment: @kevingreen: Have you got HTTPS-everywhere running in Firefox?

Comment: I do have HTTPS everywhere! Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: I wire sharked the connection, and it's definitely not leaving our network.

Comment: You know, this answer is probably a good fit for [su] or [sf].

Comment: @Cupcake: have a question in mind?