# Why does this Windows batch code cause an error when posting?

Tags: bug

If I attempt to post the code below as just a code sample, I get an error (a red box saying there was problem posting). If I wrap the code sample inside a blockquote it works.

The SO question is [Batch - Forfiles in loop with multiple file types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372515/batch-forfiles-in-loop-with-multiple-file-types).

**Code sample & Blockquote**

> ```
> for %%G in (.tga, .png) do (
>   for /f "delims=" %%A in ('forfiles /s /m *%%G /c "cmd /c echo @relpath"') do (
>     ' The ECHO below is just for testing.
>     ' Put the code from inside your FOR loop here.
>     ECHO %%A
>   )
> )
> ```

**Just code sample**

```
for %%G in (.tga, .png) do (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ('forfiles /s /m *%%G /c "cmd /c echo @relpath"') do (
    ' The ECHO below is just for testing.
    ' Put the code from inside your FOR loop here.
    ECHO %%A
  )
)
```

### Update

I didn't get the error when posting this question on Meta. But, when I was trying to post the code as part of an answer on SO I repeatedly got the error. I narrowed it down to the quote marks around `"cmd /c echo @relpath"`. If I removed those, I didn't get the error.

### Update 2

I went back to my SO answer to attempt to debug the problem. If I added the code there in a code sample inside of a blockquote and then added the same code again in *just* a code sample, it would post just fine. That explains why I didn't see the error here.

The exact error message is a red box that says *"An error occurred submitting the edit."*

[image: SO Error message]

### Update 3

It must be something in the network at work. I just tried it from home and it worked fine.

Comment: I just noticed an annoying beige popup box on the right of the post window that insisted on reminding me that I should post more than a code snippet.  Completely oblivious to the fact that I wasn't done writing the post and not going away when I added text.  Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: @HansPassant I would assume that's not it, considering _"a red box saying there was problem posting"_ was specifically mentioned in the post. Aphoria, it would be beneficial if you can give the exact error message, unless all it said was "There was a problem posting."

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't notice that message. But, I did have other text in my answer, so I maybe that message wasn't there for me to notice.

Comment: @Kendra I agree about giving the exact error message, but I didn't write it down or capture when it happened on SO. I assumed when I posted the code here I'd get the same error message and then I could note the exact message. Oops. I'm not positive, but if not exact, the message was really close to _"There was a problem posting"_.

Comment: Perhaps try editing it on the SO post again and see if you still get the error? If you do, then you can indeed get the exact quote, or even a screenshot of the error box. And if you don't, you can probably chalk it up to some odd error between you and SO. :) (Maybe check your console if you get the error again and see if  you got any odd error messages there as well.)

Comment: @Kendra See my edit. Some more info and I got the actual error message.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I attempted it myself (it should appear as a suggested edit) and didn't receive the error. If you wish to reject so you can keep it for testing/gathering any other information, please feel free.

Comment: @Kendra I accepted your edit to see it and then rolled it back. Since you didn't see the error, I thought maybe it was browser specific. I've been working in Firefox 35.0.1 but I just got the same error in Chrome 41.

Comment: It might be a network issue, something between you and SO. Do you have a mobile device you can try it on a mobile network with? Can you see any errors in the developer tools of either browser?

Comment: If you have a firewall, it might block this as a code injection attempt.

Comment: It must be something in the network at work. I just tried it from home and it worked fine. :(

Comment: This question should be marked as `status-norepo`..

Comment: @aphoria: probably a anti-hacking filter on your office network router or firewall is interrupting the POST. Same happens when [trying to post SQL answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254843/i-cant-write-drop-or-rename-table-code-in-stack-overflow-using-chrome) and certain firewalls and routers.